# Sencha Touch 2: Navigation View with cascading dataviews

Tags: view, navigation, sencha-touch-2, dataview

I'm new to Sencha Touch and mobile app development.
I need to implement in my app a main view which should look and behave like this:

```
Group1                     Group2
_________________________  _________________________
Item1     Item2     Item3  Item1     Item2     Item3

Group3                     Group4
_________________________  _________________________
Item1     Item2     Item3  Item1     Item2     Item3

Group5                     Group6
_________________________  _________________________
Item1     Item2     Item3  Item1     Item2     Item3

                         ...
```

Groups blocks bust be inlined and scroll vertically.
Items must scroll horizontally. 
Number of Items per group may vary by group.

Groups are stored in the "storeMainNavGroups" store.
Items are stored in the "storeMainNav" store, which is grouped by..."group"!

I believe that it should be accomplished by cascading dataviews:
1rst level Dataview: contains groups
2nd level Dataviews: contains items
but I'm not sure.

This is the code I tried but it does not work: All Items (for all groups) are displayed above the groups.
Code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype: 'main',
requires: ['Ext.data.Store'],
config: {
    navigationBar : {
        docked : 'top',
        items : [
            {
                name: 'btnHome',
                align: 'left',
                xtype: "button",
                iconCls: 'home',
                ui: 'plain'
            }
        ]
    },
    items: [
        {
            title: 'MyApp',
            layout: 'vbox',
            fullscreen: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: 'some text...'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'dataview',
                    id: 'listMainNavViewGroups',
                    useSimpleItems: true,
                    grouped: true,
                    inline: {
                        wrap: true
                    },
                    flex: 1,
                    itemTpl: [
                        '<div>' +
                            '<div style="display: block; float: left; font-family: Pictos; font-size: 1.5em; line-height: 120%; margin: 0 20px 0 0;">{icon}</div>' +
                            '<span style="margin: 0 40px 0 0;">{group}</span>' +
                        '</div>'
                    ],
                    store: 'storeMainNavGroups',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'dataview',
                            id: 'listMainNavView',
                            useSimpleItems: true,
                            grouped: true,
                            height: '100px',
                            inline: {
                                wrap: false
                            },
                            flex: 1,
                            itemTpl: [
                                '<div>' +
                                    '<div style="display: block; float: left; font-family: Pictos; font-size: 1.5em; line-height: 120%; margin: 0 20px 0 0;">{icon}</div>' +
                                    '<span style="margin: 0 40px 0 0;">{title}</span>' +
                                    '</div>'
                            ],
                            store: 'storeMainNav'
                        }
                    ]


                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

});

What am I doing wrong ?
Is there a better solution to accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance for your answers and advices.

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

It will become very complex the way you are doing it. Sencha doesn't like too much nesting anyway. If I were to do it, I would do something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
      extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
      xtype: 'main',
      requires: ['Ext.data.Store'],
      config: {
        navigationBar : {
          docked : 'top',
          items : [
           {
             name: 'btnHome',
             align: 'left',
             xtype: "button",
             iconCls: 'home',
             ui: 'plain'
          }]
        },
        items: [
          {
          xtype:'container',
          title: 'MyApp',
          layout: 'hbox',//Note change to hbox
          fullscreen: true,
          items:[
             { 
                 xtype:'container',
                 layout:'vbox',
                 flex:1
             },
             { 
                 xtype:'container',
                 layout:'vbox',
                 flex:1
             }
          ]
        ]
     },
     groupNumber : 0,
     initialize:function(){

         var me = this;

         //Add items dynamically here
         var leftPanel = this.getAt(0).getAt(0);
         var rightPanel = this.getAt(0).getAt(1);

         var groupStore = Ext.getStore('MainNavGroups');//This should be store id 
         var itemStore = Ext.getStore('MainNavItems');

         //Iterate through groups and add items to each

         groupStore.each(function(record){

             var groupPanel = { xtype:'container', layout:'hbox', items:[]};

             itemStore.each(function(rec){
                  //Add items to groupPanel here by filtering for group id
                  //groupPanel.add( ... );
             });

             if(me.groupNumber % 2 == 0){//Even number
               leftPanel.add(groupPanel);
             }
             else{
               rightPanel.add(groupPanel);
             }

             me.groupNumber++;
         });

         this.callParent();
     }
 });
```

Comment: Hi Abdul, Thanks for your answer. Your solution is interesting. However, I wanted to have all groups same height, and to scroll items horizontally inside each group. In fact, I think I will go simpler: a grouped list, with css styling on items to make them inlined... Anyway, navigating through this would have been too complex for the user...

Comment: If you give a height to groupPanel (say height:100) in my code, you will get all groups of equal height. Setting scrollable to true will scroll items horizontally as layout is hbox.